# trouble with writing regex java

Tags: java, regex

> String  always consists of two distinct alternating characters. For example, if string 's two distinct characters are x and y, then t could be xyxyx or yxyxy but not xxyy or xyyx.

But `a.matches()` always returns false and output becomes 0. Help me understand what's wrong here.

```
public static int check(String a) {
    char on = a.charAt(0);
    char to = a.charAt(1);
    if(on != to) {
        if(a.matches("["+on+"("+to+""+on+")*]|["+to+"("+on+""+to+")*]"))  { 
            return a.length();
        }            
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is a single character string valid? what about empty string?

Comment: they are invalid but i didnt check them  :] @Austin_Anderson

Comment: If you always have an even length of a string, you good do it with the following regex: `(..)\1`
It only turns false if the length is odd.

Comment: @JurrianFahner *"If you always have an even length"* Question explicitly lists two odd-length examples, so that is a obviously not the case.

Comment: `[]` is "any char in this set". You need to use group `()` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use regex `(.)(.)(?:\1\2)*\1?`.

- `(.)` Match any character, and capture it as group 1
- `(.)` Match any character, and capture it as group 2
- `\1` Match the same characters as was captured in group 1
- `\2` Match the same characters as was captured in group 2
- `(?:\1\2)*` Match 0 or more *pairs* of group 1+2
- `\1?` Optionally match a dangling group 1

Input must be at least two characters long. Empty string and one-character string will not match.

As java code, that would be:

```
if (a.matches("(.)(.)(?:\\1\\2)*\\1?")) {
```

See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/UfV2Il/1) for working examples<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1) Note that regex101 requires use of `^` and `$`, which are implied by the `matches()` method. It also requires use of flags `g` and `m` to showcase multiple examples at the same time.</sup>

---

**UPDATE**

As [pointed out by Austin Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310731/trouble-with-writing-regex-java/45310904?noredirect=1#comment77584550_45310904):

> fails on `yyyyyyyyy` or `xxxxxx`

To prevent that, we can add a zero-width negative lookahead, to ensure input doesn't start with two of the same character:

`(?!(.)\1)(.)(.)(?:\2\3)*\2?`

See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/UfV2Il/2).

Or you can use [Austin Anderson's simpler version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310731/trouble-with-writing-regex-java/45310904?noredirect=1#comment77584947_45310904):

`(.)(?!\1)(.)(?:\1\2)*\1?`

Comment: @ashwinmurthy You used char set `[]` instead of group `()`

Comment: @ashwinmurthy Your use of `[]` is wrong. If input is `xyxyx`, you build the following regex: `[x(yx)*]|[y(xy)*]`. The character class `[x(yx)*]` means "match any single character that is `x`, `(`, `y`, `)`, or `*`" (duplicate `x` ignored. As such, `[x(yx)*]` is same as `[xy()*]` and `[y(xy)*]` is same as `[xy()*]`, so entire `[x(yx)*]|[y(xy)*]` regex is same as `[xy()*]`, which will only match a one-character string with one of those characters. Since you know input is at least two characters long, it can never match.

Comment: yeah got it now :)

Comment: @ashwinmurthy And if you just replaced `[]` with `()` like Tezra suggests, you will only match odd-length inputs, so still not correct.

Comment: Or if you want a shorter version: `\b(.)?(.).\2\1`

Comment: fails on `yyyyyyyyy` or `xxxxxx`

Comment: @Austin_Anderson In the question is given: String always consists of two distinct alternating characters. 

I assumed that your cases were checked elsewhere.

Comment: @JurrianFahner That regex will certainly not work, since third character can be *anything*.

Comment: @Austin_Anderson If preventing that is needed, it can be fixed by adding a zero-width look-ahead, to ensure input doesn't start with two of the same character: `(?!(.)\1)(.)(.)(?:\2\3)*\2?`

Comment: @Andreas You mean without the last question mark? On http://regexr.com/ it matches many strings. But without the last question mark, it works like charm...

Comment: @Andreas beat me to it, I just came up with `"(.)(?!\\1)(.)(?:\\1\\2)*\\1?"` myself

Comment: @Austin_Anderson Even better (simpler).

Comment: @JurrianFahner The problem with regexr is the same as with regex101. You need to add `^` and `$`, to ensure it only matches *entire* input. Those anchors are implicit when using `matches()`, as I already explained in the answer.

Comment: @Austin_Anderson Your contributions have been added to answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually your regex is almost correct but problem is that you have enclosed your regex in 2 character classes and you need to match an optional 2nd character in the end.

You just need to use this regex:

```
public static int check(String a) {
    if (a.length() < 2)
        return 0;
    char on = a.charAt(0);
    char to = a.charAt(1);
    if(on != to) {
        String re = on+"("+to+on+")*"+to+"?|"+to+"("+on+to+")*"+on+"?";
        System.out.println("re: " + re);
        if(a.matches(re))  { 
            return a.length();
        }            
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/JBFEY8)

Comment: This will only match odd-length inputs.